# How to remove a file with Extents attribute, from Linux

Tags: linux, centos, ext4

in CentOS, ext4 filesystem, I have a file that has the "extents" attribute, but I can't remove that file

```
-------------e-- index.php
```

`rm -f` does nothing (nor I get an error message)

tried to remove the attribute with `chattr` but, as the documentation states, it's not removable with `chattr`.

Can't find this on the internet. Only what it is but not how to remove the file.

ADDED `strace rm -rf` trace

```
execve("/usr/bin/rm", ["rm", "-rf", "index.php"], 0x7ffeaa85f270 /* 23 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x900000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fbe0ed2e000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=44848, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 44848, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbe0ed23000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0`&\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2156592, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3985920, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbe0e740000
mprotect(0x7fbe0e904000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fbe0eb03000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1c3000) = 0x7fbe0eb03000
mmap(0x7fbe0eb09000, 16896, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fbe0eb09000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fbe0ed22000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fbe0ed20000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fbe0ed20740) = 0
access("/etc/sysconfig/strcasecmp-nonascii", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/sysconfig/strcasecmp-nonascii", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mprotect(0x7fbe0eb03000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x60d000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7fbe0ed2f000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7fbe0ed23000, 44848)           = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x900000
brk(0x921000)                           = 0x921000
brk(NULL)                               = 0x921000
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=106172832, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 106172832, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbe081fe000
close(3)                                = 0
ioctl(0, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
lstat("/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "index.php", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=4532, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
unlinkat(AT_FDCWD, "index.php", 0)      = 0
lseek(0, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
close(0)                                = 0
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

STRACE `unlink`

```
execve("/usr/bin/unlink", ["unlink", "index.php"], 0x7ffe5da1b8f8 /* 23 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x25fe000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3f6d901000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=44848, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 44848, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f3f6d8f6000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0`&\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2156592, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3985920, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f3f6d313000
mprotect(0x7f3f6d4d7000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f3f6d6d6000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1c3000) = 0x7f3f6d6d6000
mmap(0x7f3f6d6dc000, 16896, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3f6d6dc000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3f6d8f5000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3f6d8f3000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f3f6d8f3740) = 0
access("/etc/sysconfig/strcasecmp-nonascii", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/sysconfig/strcasecmp-nonascii", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mprotect(0x7f3f6d6d6000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x605000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7f3f6d902000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f3f6d8f6000, 44848)           = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x25fe000
brk(0x261f000)                          = 0x261f000
brk(NULL)                               = 0x261f000
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=106172832, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 106172832, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f3f66dd1000
close(3)                                = 0
unlink("index.php")                     = 0
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Comment: The `extents` attribute is likely a red herring and is probably not your problem; it just describes how data is stored on the disk (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/360398/168757 for a description).  It shouldn't impact your ability to delete files.

Comment: ("extent" with a t, not "extend". There are also "extended attributes", just that they're a different thing.)

Comment: and yes, the `e` flag in itself doesn't affect how a file can or can not be deleted. There's something else going on. Run e.g. `strace rm -rf` and see what it says about the `unlink()` call?

Comment: @ilkkachu, just added the traces for both rm and unlink (none worked)

Comment: also changed to extents. Thanks, it's important to use the right terminology to help others.

Comment: @StephenHarris, thanks. In fact, it's not that. I have another file on the same folder that has the same attribute.
It's the only attribute the file shows and I can manipulate it so, it shouldn't be the extents attribute.

Thank you so much. I'll inform when I figure this out. I had the same case some months ago and I was able to fix that.. should have kept some notes :(

Comment: ok, found the issue.

 ls -i index.php , rm and then again ls -i showed that the inode change so, the file was deleted and then re-created

I had a running process in php (client wp was hacked) that recreated the file as soon as I deleted it.

Thank you for everybody's contribution!

Comment: @dsantos80 could you either post that as an answer to your own question, or delete the question? +

Answer (score 1):

The extent attribute is likely a red herring. Perhaps you are really deleting the file, but it gets created again (by a malicious process) so quickly that you don't notice the delete worked?